# c# An object reference is required for the non-static method

Tags: c#

I want to use the text from a textbox in a static method that displays a column in my SQL Database. How can I do that? If I execute my code below, I have this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static method.

This is my static method:

```
static void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
        {

        SqlConnection Cn;
        SqlCommand Cmd;
        //SqlCommand Cmd1;

        Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-    ODCFVR1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RFID;Integrated Security=True");
        Cn.Open();

         // This event handler is called asynchronously 
        // when tag reports are available.
        // Loop through each tag in the report 
        // and print the data.
        foreach (Tag tag in report)
        {

            MessageBox.Show ("voici l'antenne :"+ tag.AntennaPortNumber +", EPC :"+ tag.Epc);

            Cmd = new SqlCommand ("INSERT INTO EPC (Epc_CODE) values('" + tag.Epc + "')", Cn);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand Cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            Cmd1.CommandText = " select * from Epc Where EPC_code = '" +     tag.Epc + "' ";
            Cmd1.Connection = Cn;
            String result = " ";
            Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = Cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            textBox5.Text = result; // here is my problem


            Cn.Close();
        }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: `textBox5` appears to be an instance member. drop static from your method.

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing an instance member in a static method. You could either:

- `return Cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` and set the textbox text in the calling methdo
- or pass an `Action<string>` delegate which sets the textbox text
- make your method an instance method (remove the `static` modifier)

As your method looks like some sort of event handler, I wouldn't make it static.

*Summary: You have to remove the access to nonstatic members (textbox) or make your method nonstatic.*

Comment: if i make my method nonstatic, i can execute my code without errors but there is nothing that appears in textbox text . otherwise I am a beginner in c# @ventiseis can you show how can i apply one of the first two ways.

Comment: Your problem is not the static method. Your event is simple not called - so something with the setup seems to be wrong. I would advice you to provide a matching question title and provide additional details (what framework are you using, what hardware is involved). *Otherwise, you won't get a helpful answer.* We can not guess your enviornment.